# Insertion of a node into a binary tree raises error: Node object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I get the following error on the line `self.root.right.insert(val)`:

> AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'insert'

This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def insert(self, val):
        new_node = Node(val)
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = new_node
            return
        else:
            if self.root.data > val:
                if self.root.left is not None:
                    self.root.left.insert(val)
                else:
                    self.root.left = new_node
                    return
            elif self.root.data < val:
                if self.root.right is not None:
                    self.root.right.insert(val)
                else:
                    self.root.right = new_node
                    return

bt1 = BST()
bt1.insert(1)
bt1.insert(2)
bt1.insert(0)
bt1.insert(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is no `insert` method on the `Node` class, only on the `BST` class. When you call `self.root.right.insert(val)`, you try to access a method on the `Node` class (because `self.root.right` is a `Node` instance), but that method is not defined.

Not your question, but it is also a waste that a `new_node` is created when it is not yet sure that the function will use it. It will discard it when making the recursive call. So it is better to delay the creation of that `Node` instance, until it is sure you need it there and then.

Here is the correction of your code:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    # Define the method also on the Node class:
    def insert(self, val):
        if self.data > val:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.insert(val)
            else:
                self.left = Node(val)  # Only create the instance here
        elif self.data < val:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.insert(val)
            else:
                self.right = Node(val)  # ...or here.

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def insert(self, val):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(val)
        else:  # Defer the job to to the method on the Node class
            self.root.insert(val)
```